# Kernel upgrade failing for Debian Jessie to Debian Stretch Upgrade

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am attempting to upgrade Debian 8 Jessie to Debian 10 Buster and for this I have attempted to first do Jessie to Stretch upgrade then thereafter do a Stretch to Buster upgrade.

However during the jessie (8) to stretch (9) upgrade i have encountered the following kernel upgrade issue :
[image: KernelException]

I am following the guide from [Upgrade Jessie to Stretch](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-debian-8-jessie-to-debian-9-stretch)
What am I missing?

Comment: im unsure what kernel package has been installed in the past, maybe a workaround with installation if a ither kerbel version may help

Answer (score 0):

it's been some time since I did this upgrade but I suggest to follow this article: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-upgrade-debian-8-jessie-to-9-stretch/

in the end it seems that both are +/- doing the same thing, however I advise not to run things such as `apt autoremove` to avoid the issue you see in the screenshot provided.

Also know debian kernels can co-exist meaning you can keep the old kernel and have also the new kernel and grub will boot the new one by-default. This means you can keep the old kernel and have new kernel in place at the same time.